# Passing parameters within a jQuery function fails .fadeOut()

Tags: jquery

Im trying to pass parameters to myFunction, but it seems to be causing issues because it is inside a jQuery function. Any tips?

```
//this works fine
myFunction(1);

//this doesn't work fine!
$('myObj').fadeOut(1000, myFunction(1));
```

Comment: try this way `$(element).fadeOut(1000, function(){ myFunction(1); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a bit excessive, but did you try calling the function in the callback?

```
$('myObj').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    myFunction(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

> If you’d like to send arguments to your callback function, you may
>   define a new anonymous function that calls your parameterized
>   function. For example:
>
> var pageUrl = generateNextPageUrl(); $(“#content”).fadeOut(1000,
>   function () { refreshContent(pageUrl) });
>
> Without the anonymous function definition, my suposed callback was
>   called immediatly (sic) without waiting to finish the fadeout effect.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the reference of the function

```
$('myObj').fadeOut(1000, myFunction);
```

but the callback function isn't sent any parameter, so you'll need to set your parameter somewhere else. e.g.:

```
var time = 1;
function myFunction(){
    time += 1 // do anything you want with the parameter
}
```